# Loading Time on Mobile Phone

Tags: forms, mobile, loading, uploading, timeout

I have a mobile feature where a user enters data into one form then hits send. We then load data to return back to the user. The big variable is the user's connection based on their mobile phone. User's with a strong connection will see the data come back fast, but user's with a slow connection will have to wait.

1. Is it better to have the system always load and if it's taking too long just have the user refresh the page? Or is it better to timeout after x seconds and send them to an error page to try again?
2. How long should x seconds be before we return an error page to retry.

Comment: Related information can be found in this answer: http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/59734/5591